# Error in asMethod(object), Discretize columns first error with Apriori

Tags: r, data-mining, apriori

The only clue as to what I needed to fix the this error was to make the levels of the 3 features factors. I tried that but still doesn't work.

Then does the error saying my columns are not logical have anything to do with it? What does not logical mean in this case?

So an image of the error and what the data looks like for those columns is included  here:

[image: error information and my data]

---

#### Solved

Found my problem!, the code for discretizing my columns created new variables, and didn't change the columns in my data set. So that is why I kept getting the error.

Comment: Please provide a minimal reproducible example. See e.g. ?dput...

Comment: Please move your solution to an answer of its own, thank you.